# Confusion about removing duplicates in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, duplicates

I'd like some clarification on what the size-- specifically does for this, because the code did not run as expected until I added that. I thought the for loop accounted for change in size with each iteration?

```
 public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> members)
    {
        int size = members.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
            if(members.get(i).equals(members.get(j)))
            {
             members.remove(i);
             i--;
             size--;
            }
            }
        }
        return members;
```

I understand what the rest of the code does for the method to account for the changes that occur in an ArrayList when something is removed, but i'm still confused on what that size-- does.

Comment: *I thought the for loop accounted for change in size with each iteration?* What makes you think that? You only call `size()` once.

Comment: I think you should be removing element `j`, and decrementing `j`, rather than `i`. I can't be certain that it's wrong like this, but it's a lot harder to reason that it's _right_.

Answer (score 3):

`members.remove(i);` removes the element at `i` from `members`. Thus the `size` of `members` has changed (and recall you started with `int size = members.size();` so `size` is literally meant to represent `members.size()`). This method could be simplified with a `Set`, like

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> members) {
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (String s : members) {
        set.add(s);
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}
```

Comment: Or even `return new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(members));`